How to resolve hostname by mDNS?
I am using Ubuntu 22.04. I want to be able to resolve hostname of a device connected to my local network. The device is publishing its hostname using mDNS. On my machine, I am able to ping device.local, but nslookup returns:

** server can't find device.local: NXDOMAIN

avahi-resolve also return proper address.
In nsswitch.conf I have:
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] 

Note that the device has static IP address. The device.local is not know to my DNS server and I want to keep that in this way.
I tried various modification of nsswitch.conf and dnsmasq config modifications. I was expecting nslookup to be able to resolve address of the device but without results.
Adding entry in /etc/hosts works but I don't like this solution as address of the device could change in the future.

nslookup is specifically a troubleshooting tool for regular (non-multicast) DNS only. It deliberately ignores /etc/nsswitch.conf and contacts the first DNS server listed in /etc/resolv.conf unless you explicitly specify some other DNS server to query.
avahi-resolve is a similarly dedicated tool for mDNS: it will always use mDNS only.
Instead, use e.g. getent hosts device.local or getent ahosts device.local. Those commands will use the hostname resolution methods configured in /etc/nsswitch.conf, doing exactly what most actual applications do when resolving hostnames.

All clear. Unfortunately Prometheus service returns lookup error when I use hostname in its config file but I guess it is Prometheus bug?

Maybe. Assuming you mean this one; I haven't used it and only know what a quick web browsing told me about it, though. I'd guess that it might do some internal DNS caching or optimized querying, as it is expected to be able to efficiently and repeatedly contact a large number of systems to monitor them.
